# Does Extra Damage on Abilities Round Down?

Tags: league-of-legends

For abilities in League of Legends, does extra damage on abilities (AD and AP Scaling) round down to the number shown on the ability tool tip? Or does it stay at the actual number. I'm especially curious for percentage health skills.

Comment: dupe of http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/109779/23311

Comment: @gbn Per [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/is-a-question-a-duplicate-just-because-it-asks-for-something-that-can-be-part-of?cb=1) I'd be inclined to disagree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=37347) from 2009, damage is calculated with the most precise numbers possible.

For example: suppose I'm a Level 1 Annie with no items, runes or masteries. I'm at `263/460 HP` right now, and I have `30 MR`. Elise has no MPen and she throws a Level 1 Neurotoxin, which deals `40 + 8% current HP`, at me. The raw damage would be `40 + 0.08 * 263 = 61.04`. After MR, it deals `61.04 * 100 / (100 + 30) = 46.95(...)` damage to me. I take that amount of damage, leaving me at `216.05 HP`. This will be displayed as `216 HP`.

So, in short, it stays at the actual number, then when all calculations are complete and the final damage amount is determined, that number is subtracted from the current HP of the victim. Health will be rounded on the display, though it appears that so long as you have more than `0 HP` (even at `0.01 HP`), the display will show `1 HP`.

Comment: This is right, but doesn't exactly answer my question. I figured it out through hohums's answer in the thread you linked. This answers how percent health damage affects the target, not how extra damage from AP/AD is factored into that damage. Perhaps if you edited this, quoting hohums's post, it would answer it much better. Thank you, Jonny